# wrong constructor argument type, PySide

Tags: python, arguments, pyside

Well I can't figure out this issue, I am tryinf to fix something more complicated, and suddenly python came up with this:

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):            
        super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

...
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):   

    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.mainWidget = MainWidget(MainWindow)
```

and my IDE is saying that:

```
File "/home/maze/Develop/StartApp/startapp.py", line 47, in __init__
    super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QWidget(Shiboken.ObjectType)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget = None, PySide.QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags = 0)
```

I think, before it was working that way...
Could You show me whats it about? Thanks for Your time.

Comment: whole code -->  http://pastebin.com/yLPWkucZ

Comment: The whole code is not helpful, please cut it down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the issue.

Comment: I paste the minimal part of code in my first post, Can You see it, don't You?  The whole code I paste, for those who want take a look.

Comment: That is not a minimal example; it doesn't include any imports and just stops part-way through

Comment: Ok I understand now, You make it clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `MainWidget` constructor with an object type as parameter instead of an object instance in the constructor of `MainWindow`.

You should have:

```
self.mainWidget = MainWidget(self)
```

instead of:

```
self.mainWidget = MainWidget(MainWindow)
```